# Having trouble removing white bar at bottom of screen

Tags: reactjs

I noticed a white bar on the bottom of the screen after turning on night mode which turns the background a dark purple (triggered by pressing the moon on the right). I've tried changing the padding and margins but nothing I try has gotten rid of this white bar. I believe the index.html is causing the problem but I have the margin set correctly so I don't know how to fix the margins.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import NightsStayIcon from '@material-ui/icons/NightsStay';
import AddBoxRoundedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AddBoxRounded';
import { Button , TextField, IconButton} from '@material-ui/core'; 


function App() {

  const[isNightMode, setIsNightMode] = React.useState(false)

  const [nightMode, setNightMode] = React.useState({
    background: "#FFFFFF",
    banner: "#3F51B5",
    bannerText: "#FFFFFF",
    listText: "#000000",
    inputBackground: "FFFFFF"
  });

  function nightmode(){
    
    if(isNightMode){ 
      setIsNightMode(false);  
    }
    else{
      setIsNightMode(true);
    }

    if(isNightMode){
      setNightMode(
        {
          background: "#413250", 
          bannerText: "#413250",
          listText: "#FFFFFF", 
          banner: "#FFFFFF",
          inputBackground: "FFFFFF"
        });   
    }
    else{
      setNightMode({
        background: "#FFFFFF" ,
        bannerText: "#FFFFFF" ,
        listText: "#000000",
        banner: "#3F51B5",
        inputBackground: "FFFFFF"
      });
    }
  }

  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([
    {
      text: "Learn about React",
      isCompleted: true
    },
  ]);

  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const addTodo = text => {
    const newTodos = [...todos, { text }];
    setTodos(newTodos);
  };
 
  return (
    <div style={{padding: 50, flexDirection: 'column', backgroundColor: nightMode.background}}>

      <div> 
        <div style = {{display: 'flex', fontFamily: 'Work Sans', fontSize: 25 , marginBottom: 25, color: '#CDCACA'}}>
          <text>Good Morning</text>
        </div> 
      </div> 

      <Card style = {{width: window.innerWidth/4, borderRadius: 30, backgroundColor: nightMode.banner, color: nightMode.bannerText}}>
        <CardContent>
          <div style = {{display: 'flex', fontFamily: 'Work Sans', fontSize: 55}}>
            <text>Tuesday</text>
          </div>

          <text style = {{display: 'flex', fontFamily: 'Work Sans', fontSize: 45}}>11:45</text>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
      
      <div style = {{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}>
        <IconButton onClick = {nightmode}>
          <NightsStayIcon/>
        </IconButton>
      </div>

    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>React App</title>
    <style>
      html,body, #root {
        height: 50%;
      }

      body{
        margin: 0;
        background-color: #ffffff;          //**This section is causing the issue
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: when running the code I can't see any white bar https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-playground-forked-c7wke?file=/public/index.html

Comment: @Kuf press the moon button on the right side and it'll switch to night mode. The white bar should be visible when the background changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
html,body, #root {
  height: 50%;
}
```

To 100% and add the same css directive (`height: "100%"`) to the parent div in the react code.

## [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-playground-forked-c7wke?file=/public/index.html)

Comment: Thank you, the additional height configuration in the parent div fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

There may be some margin being placed by default on your html/body element. In a sandbox I spun up with your code, it was the body applying a default 8px margin.

```
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: I have an index.css and app.css file do I alter the margin using these files? I tried copying your code into the index.css but it didn't have an effect. I'll add them to the original post I'm not very familiar with CSS.